# How do I detect whether a MySQL database is running or not?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using XAMPP and I want to detect whether the MySQL database is running or not. My code looks like this:

```
$this->connection = mysqli_connect(
        $this->host,
        $this->name,
        $this->pass,
        $this->db
);

if ($this->connection->connect_errno)
{
        $this->connection = false;
        return false;
} else { $this->connection->set_charset('utf-8'); }
```

I receive the following log:

> PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused ...
>
> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in // This refers to $this->connection->connect_errno
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function set_charset() on boolean

How can I prevent this? How can I check whether the database in general is available or not?

Comment: Perform your connection in a `try / catch` statement so that you can gracefully handle errors.

Comment: CAn you show the whole class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you'll want to either disable warning reports or suppress them for `mysqli_connect` call, or embed it in a `try/catch` block.

Then, instead of checking `connect_errno`, instead first verify that `connection` is a truthy value. Like so

```
$this->connection = false;
try {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
            $this->host,
            $this->name,
            $this->pass,
            $this->db
    );
    if (!$this->connection || $this->connection->connect_errno)
    {
        $this->connection = false;
        return false;
    } else { 
        $this->connection->set_charset('utf-8'); 
    }
} catch ($e) { //something bad happened. Probably not recoverable.
    $this->connection = false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Never suppress warnings, that is a *bad* plan.

Comment: I agree, I'm never a fan of suppressing warnings so I'm certainly open to suggestions, but this code should be situationally complete enough to handle any issues. How would you approach it?

Comment: I would put the connection in a `try / catch` so that errors can be handled more appropriately.

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware that warnings would actually be properly catchable. Thanks for the tip. I've improved my answer.

Comment: May I ask why my edits were rolled back? I feel that they offered substantial improvement :(

Comment: It's a style choice. I prefer else's for clarity even if they are extraneous. Particularly in educational examples like this one.

Comment: I guess large scale edits (or rollbacks) deserve a word or two down here. Not talking to you @JayBlanchard, but rather YCS

Comment: It's your answer, you can edit it as you see fit (as long as you're not defacing it). If this results in a rollback war, flag for mod help.

Comment: Meta post about the edits on this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/ (cc @YourCommonSense)

Answer (score 2):

> I am not the author of this answer, it's just the original version of the other post, which is the only correct solution for the conditions given

First you'll want to either disable warning reports or suppress them for `mysqli_connect` call.

Then, instead of checking `connect_errno`, first verify that `connection` is a truthy value. Like so

```
$this->connection = @mysqli_connect( //<-- warnings suppressed
        $this->host,
        $this->name,
        $this->pass,
        $this->db
);

if (!$this->connection || $this->connection->connect_errno) //lazy evaluation will prevent any issues here
{
        $this->connection = false;
        return false;
} else { $this->connection->set_charset('utf-8'); }
```